# Regex to find an ID code within an email subject?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, email

We are implementing a feature in our web application that reads email subjects and checks the subject for a certain string containing an ID so that we can match incoming emails to projects in our application.

A subject may look like this:

```
OVE.com: Purchase Confirmation (2007 Subaru Impreza Wagon 2.5i JF1GG61677G808577 PEDDLE LLC)
```

Where `(2007 Subaru Impreza Wagon 2.5i JF1GG61677G808577` is a dynamic part.

I need to identify the string of 17 digits (i.e. `JF1GG61677G808577`) from email subject.

Comment: Is it always 17 digits? What's the pattern of these confirmation codes?

Comment: yes, it is always 17 digit. @TahTatsumoto

Comment: Is there a pattern? Otherwise you might want to consider parsing instead.

Comment: Yes, it follows a particular pattern based on input.

Comment: Is it only digits? In your example you have letters and digits. If there can be digits and letters - is always uppercase letters? If only digits this pattern should work: \d{17}, if uppercase letters and digits: [\dA-Z]{17}.

Comment: It is combination of letters and digits. @Klaudiuszbryjamus

Comment: So as I mention this pattern should work: [\da-zA-z]{17}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the sample snippet,

```
string strRegex = @"[A-Z0-9]{17}";

Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"OVE.com: Purchase Confirmation (2007 Subaru Impreza Wagon 2.5i JF1GG61677G808577 PEDDLE LLC)";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```